# Can not access DfsrPrivate

Tags: windows, replication, dfs, dfs-r, deleting

I've set up DFS-R between three servers, and so far, it is replicating everything as its supposed to.

- The problem is, I can not access the `DfsrPrivate` folder. Where is it located? So far I see the link/shortcut from within my replicated folder. But I get an `access denied`, when trying to open it.

  I can open and browse the `DfsrPrivate` when I'm trying to specify another staging folder through DFS' own configuration, but I can not see *files*, only *folders*.
- Do files/folders I deleted while having an active DFS replication group, get deleted permanently or does it store it in the `Deleted` folder under `DfsrPrivate`?
- Another "bonus" question: If you're dealing with around 500gb of images, how large a staging quota do you recommend? Is there any "Best Practice"?

Thanks.

Comment: Re not being able to access folder: Kill explorer and restart explorer from elevated cmd. See: https://serverfault.com/questions/123933/how-do-i-run-an-elevated-explorer-on-w8r2-with-default-uac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be a Domain Admin to override the permissions and view the `DfsrPrivate` folder (located in the DFS root folder; should be able to pull up `\\domain\dfs_root\DfsrPrivate`). It does contain a `Deleted` folder within it, but it should manage the size of that folder automatically. Deleted items are moved to the `Deleted` folder until **all** partners in the replication have moved it there, then it's actually deleted.

The Staging size must be *at least* as large as the largest file you want replicated (best practice: take 10 file from the 10th percentiles, the staging should be the sum of their sizes).

Comment: I've asked the domain admin to change rights, so a specific usergroup and I, got full rights over the DfsrPrivate folder, though, i still cant open the folder, permission denied.. It says its "Domain Bases in Windows 2000 Server mode" could that be the reason?

Comment: I figured it out, I can access the Dfsrprivate folder through the DFS program, under the namespace, when I click "Open in Explorer" thought, I cant open on the server on which I'm logged in. Only the two others.

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Access problem: run elevated.

On Win2008r2: Kill explorer. Restart explorer from elevated shell.

From an elevated CMD:

```
tskill explorer & explorer
```

See also: [How do I run an elevated explorer on W8R2 with default UAC?](https://serverfault.com/questions/123933/how-do-i-run-an-elevated-explorer-on-w8r2-with-default-uac)

## 2. "Deleted" folder only used when checkbox non-default.

Short explanation here. Long explanation see link.

- In the default configuration that folder is not used and will remain empty. Instead killed files are placed in `ConflictAndDeleted` until that quota runs over. Then they are thrown out. Then that's permanent.
- In the non-default configurations, the `Deleted` folder will be used as a very, very brief temporary cache for death bound files when the execution order has just come in from an outside DFSR partner server. That's permanent then. (Please excuse the violent language.)

In depth explanation by Ned Pyle see below.

- 2008-08-18, Microsoft TechNet, AskDs blog, Ned Pyle, [*What is the purpose of the ‘Deleted’ folder in DFSR?*](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/08/18/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-deleted-folder-in-dfsr/) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/M6M4X).)

## 3. Use at least sum of 32 largest files for staging size.

- Short answer: sum of 32 largest files as minimum.
- Long answer: PowerShell script and in depth explanation see link.

  - 2011-07-13, Microsoft TechNet, AskDs blog, Ned Pyle, [*How to Determine the Minimum Staging Area DFSR Needs for a Replicated Folder*](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/07/13/how-to-determine-the-minimum-staging-area-dfsr-needs-for-a-replicated-folder/) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/H9qk9).)